# Firefox/Chrome Shell for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have googled my tail off - but can't seem to find what I am looking for. In Ubuntu (or any Linux distro for that matter) is there a way to set the GUI shell to only be Firefox or Chrome. Meaning - I don't need an entire desktop environment - just the one application.

I am pretty much trying to figure out a Linux equivalent to changing `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` from `explorer.exe` to `firefox.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, distributions are setup the way that a display manager is fired up right after the X server. For Gnome, that would be GDM, for KDE that would be KDM etc. What you need to do is to replace a Window manager with a custom application, which in your case is a web browser. Generally, you can achieve this by putting your command(s) into `~/.xinitrc`  and `~/.xsession` files, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
firefox &
```

For Ubuntu, this process is explained in details [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomXSession). Other distros are quite similar.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!